Do significant numbers of people report colour vision even at very low light intensities?
I was explaining to a 16 year old how rods and cones in the eyes work. I said to him that that is why everything looks black and white at night.
To my great suprise he told me he had never experienced this, he could always see things in colour no matter how dark it gets. We talked about it for some time as I was so suprised and wanted to make sure I had understood him correctly.
Obviously I cannot see through another person's eyes but I was convinced that this serious and intelligent young man was telling me the truth.
He also has extraordinary mathematical abilities and thrives with most aspects of learning.
I searched online and found a paper that claims that there is indeed colour vision at low light intensities.
My own experience is that after sunset, I can see well enough where everything is but can no longer distinguish between my blue,brown and green recycling bins by colour.
https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/12974325/
Do many other people report being able to see colours at all times, even in very low light intensities?

This is a great question! There is certainly some color vision at lower light intensities, but my guess is that the difference between you and the other person is at a higher perceptual level than that based on how much confidence you're each placing on prior information about what colors things are. The fun classroom demo of this is to use something without much prior information, like squares of different-colored construction paper, and have students write on them the colors they think they are in the dark, and then bring them into the light to compare to actual colors.

The question, though, would be what proportion of people think more like you (nighttime = more black-and-white) and what proportion of people think more like them (nighttime = I can still see color), and whether there is any relationship to your actual ability to discriminate ambiguous colors in that setting.

Using OP's example of the recycling bins, I take mine out at night and I can definitely distinguish blue and green even on a cloudy night on a street with no streetlights. It's not easy and I have to look more closely, but I can see the colors. But I'm skeptical of the boy's claim he can see color without being diminished. I suspect he's simply never really paid attention to it and tried to objectively gauge how much color loss he experiences.

@CareyGregory Indeed tbe blue, green and brown recycling bins do not look identical to me at night, they seem very slightly different shades of brownish-grey. It extremely difficult for me to work out which shade corresponds with the colours I know in daylight. It is much simpler to open the  bin and see which recycling is inside it.

On a practical note. It has just occurred to me that if I add bright white lettering, that can easily be read in low light levels to my bins,  I can save myself the trouble of looking inside them to distinguish between them.

As a child I noticed that I could easily see colour at night by moonlight (no streetlights nearby), and still can (at 40+) if dark adjusted, even at less than quarter moon.  There's diminution of intensity; dark shades and similar shades harder to distinguish, but can tell brown from red and green for instance. Streetlights are problematic in that it's either sodium lamp or LED these days, both of which have odd spectra for colour identification. These give quite bright light by scattering from cloud cover with no lights nearby, but I can still tell colours without too much difficulty.

Thanks @bob1 I wonder how many other people are like you the teenager I was speaking with. After all there is a great deal of variation in human senses. I can hear a car approaching on a empty country road long before my friends, with no hearing problems, can hear it. I can hear conversations happening several rooms away and sometimes need to put my fingers in my ears out of respect for people's privacy.

Back in 2020 I had a very bad ear infection. The ENT consultant who advised me afterwards, that such a bad infection always causes some degree of hearing loss. I assured him I could hear well enough for conversation and other everyday activities. It seems that even with some damage my hearing is still more acute than that of the average human being.

I agree with @BryanKrause that there is an unfathomable amount of upstream processing happening in the primary visual cortex and the secondary, tertiary etc. parts of the brain that are impossible for us to consciously experience; so it is very difficult to differentiate „inferred“ vs „true“ color. I guess that this question could be answerable with ranges of sensitivity of rods and cones between humans, but perhaps the difference between you and that individual is also that you know everything switches to black and white at night and thus your brain interprets colours this way.

I don't think seeing colors by moonlight is surprising or unusual at all. I've done a lot of camping and night hikes and at night when your eyes are adapted to the dark, a full or nearly full moon is easily enough to see by without a flashlight.

This is a fascinating topic. I’ve found loads of stuff on photopic, mesopic and scotopic vision, but I can’t find anything on differences between people!

@Casey Gregory my night vision is good. I remember going camping when I was 26 and suprising my friends by being able to read my  novel by moonlight. I have not tried in recent decades to see if I still can. I can still move about at night pefectly safely. Neither when I was young,  nor now can I distinguish colours.
